# Is there a way to make a request to a site hosted on local IIS from a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got a site running on my dev machine running in a docker container, and it needs to make a request to a site hosted locally on my machine, hosted via IIS.  I've managed to get this working by specifying providing the `extra_hosts` in the docker-compose.override.yml file,

e.g.

```yaml
    extra_hosts:
      - "dev-gb.company-qa.com:192.168.65.2"
      - "dev-de.company-qa.com:192.168.65.2"
```

However the bridge IP I've specified is unique to my machine - the next dev that pulls it down will have to discover this IP and change it for themselves.  Is there a cleaner, simpler way of accessing the site hosted on my machine without having to manually bind the host name to the bridged IP?  I've read about `host.docker.internal` but I've no idea *where* that is supposed to go?

Comment: Try to use [`host` network type](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/)

Comment: @AlexeyR. I tried that, but unfortunately it didn't work.